# Simple way to have variable number of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I want to build a class with a variable number of template parameters, any easy way to get it?

```
template<class T0, class T1, ...>
class MyClass;
```

Currently I am using tuple to do it.

```
template<class Tuple>
class MyClass;
```

and use it like

```
MyClass<std::tuple<T0, T1, T2>> a;
```

Comment: search for: *variadic templates*

Comment: why do you need multiple template parameters?

Answer (score 3):

[Variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) are part of the C++11 standard.  A conformant compiler (GCC, the [latest compiler release](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) for Visual Studio 2012, etc.) will support this.

Comment: It's important to note that the linked Visual Studio download is a Community Tech Preview which is not meant to be used for production coding.

Comment: ... and is buggy as hell, to the point where we call the variadics in there "buggyadics".